# Dynamically count the number of custom post types associated to a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have two custom post types, "participants" and "reports". Both of them are associated with the custom taxonomy "year".

So in the post "report 1" that is flagged under "2023" taxonomy I want to show the number of "participants" that are flagged under the same taxonomy (2023). The "Report 2" is flagged under "2022" taxonomy and it must show the number of "participants" that are flagged under the same taxonomy (2022). And so on.

Whatever I find online, it's always hard coded. But I need it to be dynamic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get them with `WP_Query`. Creat an array then get the number of posts from `found_posts` function.

Comment: Hi Mehran. Thanks for your support.
Well, I got here:

    `<?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'category_name' => 'participantes+projetos', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1 // to retrieve all posts
    ) );
    $count = $query->found_posts;
    ?>`

Still, it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?